# Jasper pass formatted text as field Jasper change format

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a simple report like this:

[image]

I pass the info formatted like this:

`{ image deleted }`

But when I see the report I see something completely shuffle or unformatted like this:

[image]

I want the text formatted like I pass from Java. What I am doing wrong?

### Update

The periodoDisfrutado is a field from type java.lang.String and I pass from my Java a java.lang.String:

[image]

My Java class the method which is send the data to the report:

[image]

My XML file is

```
<group name="empleado">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{empleado}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="117">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="7" y="8" width="547" height="20" forecolor="#FF0000"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Empleado: " + $F{empleado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="7" y="33" width="148" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Dias de Vacaciones/Año: " + $F{diasTotal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="161" y="33" width="119" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Dias disfrutados: " + $F{gastados}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="281" y="33" width="105" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Dias restantes: " + $F{restantes}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement x="176" y="59" width="378" height="56"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{periodoDisfrutado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="7" y="59" width="169" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Periodos de vacaciones disfrutados:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
</group>
```

Comment: What datasource are you using?

Comment: It is better to post your code (sample *jrxml* + *Java* code)

Comment: The datasource is just a plain Java Class with some fields. See my edited question thanks a lot

Comment: Pass the relavant part of the jrxml file

Comment: It seems that all your "unformatted" text is in a single $field, so jasper format it as text, maybe you need to restructure data as datasource and use a subreport...

Comment: see my editd question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as I suspected you are passing a String with page break, spaces and maybe tabs. Jasper report will **not** try to format as table, it will simply display your string and depending on font type, etc you will have different result.

If you like to create a table format instead of a String you need to pass a [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html), and use for example a `subreport` to display the data.

Note: This will also greatly improve your export to excel.

The best way to setup this datasource depends on what kind of current datasource you are using, where are the `$F{periodoDisfrutado}` coming from?

Comment: i developed a subreport and works great thanks a lot petter and best regars from Venezuela..

Comment: sorry it should be etc. (et cetera, eccetera)and so on.